# The given path's format is not supported "obj\Debug\C:\..." on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build

I'm trying to build a project that wasn't created by me. VS gives me the error:

> Could not write lines to file "obj\Debug\C:\...". The given path's format is not supported.

I've replaced the full path with "...". Note that the path is interrupted with "C:..."

Anyone know what VS uses to form this path and where I might be able to change it? The file type that it is trying to write is .csprojccrefgen.rsp.

Comment: I wonder if it was migrated from an older version of MSVS: that might have corrupted it. If this happens in an appreciable number of projects and configurations it could pay to to edit the project files directly, if you can see where they are wrong - it is a real pain to correct large numbers of these things in the standard dialogues. But only do that if you are confident, and save your work first!

Comment: Can you please include the full error message?  In other words, don't abbreviate anything, and don't replace the full path with "...".  I'd like to see everything, as that might provide a clue as to which build step is causing this.  The root problem is that there is an absolute path in your project file, where VS is expecting a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was due to an invalid installation of the Code Contracts for .NET plugin for VS. I had to install the latest version from here, which resolved the issue:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid path, the `:` must not occur as a folder name. Check what is set as the output directory:

> To change the build output directory:
>
> 1. On the menu bar, choose **Project**, *Appname* **Properties**.
> 2. Choose the **Build** tab.
> 3. Choose the **Browse** button next to the **Output path** box and specify a new build output directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx

Comment: Build output path is fine. The path that VS is trying to use doesn't seem to be specified anywhere (I did a full text search of the project directory) but is generated by VS at compile time.